Optimal Data Storage Architecture for a Multi-Server SaaS System
I'm building a SaaS project with the following workflow:

A user uploads their dataset.
The dataset is preprocessed.
The preprocessed data is used for inference on a trained machine learning model.
The results are displayed to the user.

The system architecture consists of three servers:

SaaS Server: Handles user authentication and dataset uploads.
Preprocessing Server: Processes the uploaded datasets.
MLOps Server: Performs inference on the preprocessed data.

I'm trying to determine the most optimal data storage architecture for this system. After some research, I found two potential solutions:
Solution 1: Centralized DataStorage for SaaS Server

User uploads data to the SaaS server, which stores it in the datastorage .
SaaS sends the data to the Preprocessing server.
Preprocessing processes the data and sends it back to SaaS for storage.
SaaS sends the preprocessed data to MLOps.
MLOps performs inference and sends results back to SaaS for storage.
SaaS displays results to the user.

Solution 2: Shared Datastorage for All Servers

User uploads data, which the SaaS server stores in a shared datastorage.
SaaS requests preprocessing, and the Preprocessing server reads the data from the datastorage.
Preprocessing processes the data and updates it in the datastorage.
MLOps reads the preprocessed data from the datastorage.
MLOps performs inference and updates the results in the datastorage.
SaaS reads the results from the database and displays them to the user.

Questions:

Either of these approaches is not optimal? If so, why?
Are there any potential issues or bottlenecks with these solutions?
Could you suggest any alternative approaches for a more efficient data storage architecture?
Where can I find more information or resources about designing distributed systems with multiple servers?

